# Easy question on how to get rid of the Xcode navigation bar in the Main.storyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode4, xcode11, xcode12

I can only find youtube tutorials on adding navigation bars not removing them. I am creating an Xcode app and the navigation bar is blocking one of my images that is total unnecessary to be there when I change the orientation. This never happened before with Xcode 11. Right now it is happening to the updated Xcode 12. I only want to change one view controller; not the others who need the navigation item saying < Back. Just not the main login or Sign Up area.

How to I hide it or get rid of one of the nagation items on the Main.storyboard?